# JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode exception - cannot have colon(:) in name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, json.net

I need to convert JSON to XML using NewtonSoft Json.Net.  The JSON file includes data with a colon in some of the object keys.  When running the code below, it throws an exception.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
```

Exception: `The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

Here are some example key-value pairs in the JSON string:

```
'jcr:type' : 'nt:file';
'jcr:content' ['jcr:uuid' : jfkjsaf]
```

These are just randomly picked from the JSON string; both keys and values have prefixes with colons.

How can I get Json.Net to ignore this exception and convert the JSON to XML?

okay,here is my json file

```
{
    "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
    "jcr:created": "Mon Dec 30 2013 23:31:17 GMT-0800",
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:OrderedFolder",
    "CustomerImage0": {
        "id": 0,
        "firstName": "Customer",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "phone": "988-777-5550",
        "status": "Active",
        "lastName": "Image",
        "country": "India",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
    },
    "CustomerImage1": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Customer",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "phone": "988-777-5551",
        "status": "Active",
        "lastName": "Image",
        "country": "India",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
    },
    "CustomerImage2": {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Customer",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "phone": "988-777-5552",
        "status": "Active",
        "lastName": "Image",
        "country": "India",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
    },
    "CustomerImage3": {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Customer",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "phone": "988-777-5553",
        "status": "Active",
        "lastName": "Image",
        "country": "India",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
    },
    "CustomerImage4": {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Customer",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "phone": "988-777-5554",
        "status": "Active",
        "lastName": "Image",
        "country": "India",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
    },
    "Nokia_7610_white.gif": {
        "jcr:uuid": "65ce7b11-c5f1-4017-b27c-c455b1a710a1",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Fri Jan 03 2014 04:58:12 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 11886,
            "phone": "888-123-0121",
            "status": "Active",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/gif",
            "designation": "APL",
            "lastName": "Image1",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Jan 03 2014 04:57:59 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "Nokia_9300_close.gif": {
        "jcr:uuid": "619ee9eb-d73a-4a65-b7e7-8bd5c2061412",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Fri Jan 03 2014 04:59:22 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 11797,
            "phone": "888-123-0122",
            "status": "Active",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/gif",
            "designation": "APL",
            "lastName": "Image2",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Jan 03 2014 04:59:09 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "Nokia_9500_close.gif": {
        "jcr:uuid": "12a67241-aa11-4199-9b98-657406d777d6",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Fri Jan 03 2014 05:00:13 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 9873,
            "phone": "888-123-0123",
            "status": "Active",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/gif",
            "designation": "APL",
            "lastName": "Image3",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Jan 03 2014 05:00:00 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "Nokia_N90.gif": {
        "jcr:uuid": "5a01d557-1430-4d5b-a9f8-5f836f2812a7",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Fri Jan 03 2014 05:00:57 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 8841,
            "phone": "888-123-0124",
            "status": "Active",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/gif",
            "designation": "APL",
            "lastName": "Image4",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Jan 03 2014 05:00:44 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "PreviewGif.gif": {
        "jcr:uuid": "625112c6-dede-4333-8e78-fcdf474a190f",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:19:39 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 26994,
            "phone": "888-123-0125",
            "status": "Active",
            "designation": "APL",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/gif",
            "lastName": "Image5",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:19:27 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "online.png": {
        "jcr:uuid": "194f27d0-a549-493f-9c67-ac8f1ea436a5",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:23:09 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 1857,
            "phone": "888-123-0126",
            "status": "Active",
            "designation": "APL",
            "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
            "lastName": "Image6",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:22:58 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    },
    "Hot_Sale_Nike.pdf": {
        "jcr:uuid": "52084540-b409-45cd-909b-9702742428b1",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"
        ],
        "jcr:created": "Fri Jan 10 2014 01:30:48 GMT-0800",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
        "jcr:content": {
            "firstName": "Vendor",
            "companyName": "E Z Systems",
            ":jcr:data": 54909,
            "phone": "888-123-0222",
            "status": "Active",
            "designation": "APL",
            "jcr:mimeType": "application/pdf",
            "lastName": "Pdf2",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Jan 10 2014 01:30:32 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "city": "Hyderabad"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your JSON is formatted correctly?  After fixing up the examples you provided to be correctly formatted JSON, I tried the following code using the latest version of JSON.Net.  I did not see any exception converting it to XML.  It appears that Json.Net handles the colons by dropping the prefixes from the keys during the conversion.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""jcr:type"" : ""nt:file"",
            ""jcr:content"" : [""jcr:uuid"", ""jfkjsaf""]
        }";

        XmlDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
            xdoc.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <type>nt:file</type>
  <content>jcr:uuid</content>
  <content>jfkjsaf</content>
</root>
```

Things to check:

- Is your JSON valid?  You can check it using [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/).
- Are you running the latest version of Json.Net?  You can get the latest from [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or using NuGet within Visual Studio.
- Are you manipulating the JSON string in any way before calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode`?  If so, what exactly are you doing?  We need details.

If those things aren't the problem, please edit your question to provide the full JSON that you are having trouble with, not just bits and pieces.

#### UPDATE

Now that you have posted your full JSON, I can see the problem.  You have keys in your JSON that have more than one colon in them.  Here is the simplest example that produces the exception:

```
string json = @"{ "":jcr:data"": 54909 }";
XmlDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
```

It looks like the problematic keys are all the same one -- `:jcr:data`.  If you have control over the source of the JSON, then the best solution is to fix the source so that it does not have the extra colon at the start of these keys.

If the JSON is from a thrid party web service that you do not control, one simple fix is to do a string replace on the JSON before you try to convert it to XML.  You can do that like this:

```
json = json.Replace(":jcr:data", "jcr:data");
```

I tried this with your full JSON and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, for ur reply   I validated my json file, it is valid,the error i receive is :                  The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: part of json data "online.png": { "jcr:uuid": "194f27d0-a549-493f-9c67-ac8f1ea436a5","jcr:createdBy": "admin", "jcr:mixinTypes": [
            "mix:referenceable"],"jcr:created": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:23:09 GMT-0800","jcr:primaryType": "nt:file","jcr:content": {"firstName": "Vendor","companyName": "E Z Systems", ":jcr:data": 1857,"phone": "888-123-0126","status": "Active","designation": "APL","jcr:mimeType": "image/png", "lastName": "Image6",
            "jcr:lastModified": "Thu Jan 09 2014 05:22:58 GMT-0800",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured","city": "Hyderabad"
        }},

Comment: Is is possible to query jobject using linq with like search for key value and array names at any depth? If yes, please help me in writing queries, so that, I need not worry about xml conversion from json and later using xpath on converted xml for performing search operation.

Comment: the json file has no root element,it starts with multiple properties and has collection of meta data about images , I posted, a sample image metadata

Comment: exception is thrown at  deserializedValue = CreateValueInternal(reader, objectType, contract, null, null, null, null); in JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs file

Comment: You can query a `JObject` to any depth using `SelectToken`.  You can find examples of this [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) and [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm).

Comment: XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object. is the exception I found on debugging

Comment: Can you edit your original question to post the full JSON that is giving you trouble?  If you just post pieces, it is not possible to help because we need to be able to parse it.  It must be complete, correct JSON to be able to parse it.

Comment: I just edited and included the file on which I am working please go through and suggest

Comment: what would be the query for image name like search and proprties like search?

Comment: Now that you have posted your full JSON, I can see the problem with the XML conversion.  I've updated my answer with more info.  If you are having trouble with using `SelectToken` on `JObject`, please open a new question for that.

Comment: thank you, its working,now, can I get the property name value pair as attributes instead of elements?

Comment: No. If you need that, you will have to write your own code to do it.